# Creating sheets and changing reference based on record count.

Tags: excel, vba

I have simple problem, but I am not able to find a "fix" for it.

I have the following code:

```
cmdSQLData.CommandText = Query 'some select
cmdSQLData.CommandType = adCmdText
cmdSQLData.CommandTimeout = 0

Set rs = cmdSQLData.Execute()
j = 1
x = 6 'the line I want the data to start
rs.MoveFirst

Do Until rs.EOF

Sheet1.Range("A" & x).Value = rs![name1]
Sheet1.Range("B" & x).Value = rs![name2]
Sheet1.Range("C" & x).Value = rs![name3]
Sheet1.Range("D" & x).Value = rs![name4]
.
.'lot more columns
.
Sheet1.Range("AC" & x).Value = rs![name28]

If x = 10 Then    'after each 10 lines to create another sheet
x = 6
j = j + 1
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name ="Sheet" & j
End If

Loop

cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
Set cmdSQLData = Nothing
```

I need that when there are more "lines" in the record set than lets say 10, to have another sheet created, `Sheet2`, where to have the next 10 lines inserted and if the record set still has values to have another sheet created, `Sheet3` and so on, until the record set has been fully parsed.

The problem is that for getting the data from record set to excel, i use `Sheet1`, hardcoded. I tryed to use instead of `Sheet1`, `Sheet[j]` or `Sheet(j)` and to increment "j" each time I create a new sheet, but I get an error, therefore I cannot use `Sheet[j].Range("A" & x).Value=rs![name1]` or `Sheet(j).Range("A" & x).Value=rs![name1]`.

Any hints?

Comment: Don't you think it's much easier to collect all records into one sheet first and then just divide this master data into sets of ten rows each and transfer each set to individual sheets?

Comment: Why don't you try rs.recordscount to count the number of rows in recordset.. then add sheets as per your needs

Comment: I second @SathishK's suggestion. Knowing it ahead of time and preparing to add the number of sheets before retrieving data seems to be most sound. Also, your `x` here is not incrementing at all. Your code will keep on overwriting row 6 until it reaches EOF. See my answer below for the proper setting.

Answer (score 1):

While I personally believe that collecting all data into one sheet before dividing them into set of x rows is much better, there's another way of going about it using your code. Instead of using `Sheet1`, use Sheets(`j`) where `j` is the sheet index. Also, you can do Sheets("Sheet" & `j`) as well.

Using the second approach, replace the respective block of your code with the following:

```
Set rs = cmdSQLData.Execute()
j = 1
x = 6 'the line I want the data to start
rs.MoveFirst

Do Until rs.EOF

With Sheets("Sheet" & j)
    .Range("A" & x).Value = rs![name1]
    .Range("B" & x).Value = rs![name2]
    .Range("C" & x).Value = rs![name3]
    .Range("D" & x).Value = rs![name4]
.
.'lot more columns
.
    .Range("AC" & x).Value = rs![name28]
End With

x = x + 1

If x = 16 Then    'after each 10 lines to create another sheet
x = 6
j = j + 1
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Sheet" & j
End If

Loop
```

You also forgot to increment your `x` so it will keep on overwriting row 6 again and again. Here, you should be targeting `x=10` but `x=16` since you start from row 6 based on the initial value of `x`. The ten rows including row 6 ends in row 15. Once `x` is equal to `16`, it should trigger your `IF` block.

I have corrected that for you in the above code. Let us know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for adding new sheet:

```
Do Until rs.EOF

    If x = 10 Then
        Set ws = Thisworkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Thisworkbook.Sheets(Thisworksheet.Sheets.Count)
        ws.Name = "Sheet" & j
        x = 6
        j = j + 1 ' although you don't really need this, sheet number increment automatically.
    End If

    ws.Range("A" & x).Value = rs![name1]
    .
    .
    x = x + 1
Loop
```

i just assumed you only have problem on adding sheet.
Hope this helps.